# Scaling to a specific width

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I want to scale a selection of vertices to a specific size (in mm). I have a "beam" which is 1,2mm wide and I want a certain portion to be 1mm. How can I scale it to be exactly 1mm? I can approximate it by using the measurement tools, but I was wondering if there is a way to make it exactly that amount?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: With the object selected in Object mode, click the Object menu button and select Apply (or press Control-A). Then select either Apply Scale or Apply Rotation And Scale. That will keep the object the same size, but reset the scale to 1 for each dimension. After this, in the Dimension box (where you put the arrow), you can type in 1.0 for 1 mm, as it looks like your project is set for millimeter scale. You may want to repeat the Apply Scale procedure after this, as it can get confusing as the object is modified more.

Answer (score 1):

err..I deleted the faces I didn't need and closed off the resulting holes and seperated them into different objects (L to select and P - selection) and then I could set the desired width (length and height) for each object in the properties window...

[image]